# Youtube - couldn't load plug-in

Tags: google-chrome

All of a sudden there's this message of 'couldn't load plug-in' on chrome. Firefox is fine though, I tried updating flashplayer but it didn't work. Thoughts?

Comment: Very, very similar thread here: Google Chrome - couldn't load plugin - shockwave flash and a link to code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=173790. It's still flagged as "unconfirmed" despite several *me-toos*.

Comment: It's now "untriaged" but [this comment](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=173790#c31) explains the problem: "Unfortunately, 11.5.31.138 was pushed out via the component updater, and using plugins from the component updater doesn't work on Linux (and breaks stuff, due to the way plugins are loaded). :(

So deleting ~/.config/google-chrome/PepperFlash should fix things (unfortunately falling back to .137) ... and since we've stopped pushing .138, it won't reappear."

Comment: @fossfreedom Are you really sure this is offtopic? Cause you know, 5K views already, and most people don't feel like waiting until a filed bug is admitted and fixed ;)

Comment: @mlvljr - agree its annoying - yes its a bug which will be shortly fixed (see the triage comment link above) - hence, its both off-topic and too-localised.  The 5K views would be expected.  However I agree - I'll reopen for the moment - but in a few days when the bug is resolved, I'll close this again as too-localised since the question will be just for a specific moment in time.

Comment: @fossfreedom Now, that's some good moderator attitude, may be stackexchange isn't doomed :) Many thanks!

Comment: This is now supposedly fixed - can someone confirm? http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/stable-channel-update.html

Comment: The bug has been fixed. I just did an update which included Google-Chrome. But, we have to go to /home/user/.config/google-chrome and rename (or delete) the PepperFlash folder. Then open Chrome browser, which will now load the plugin from the /opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash folder. The current version is 11.5.31.138. Then, if you had enabled the Adobe version, disable it in chrome://plugins

Comment: On the other hand you can consider viewing videos with HTML5 version of YouTube. You can join the opt-in trial here: http://www.youtube.com/html5

Answer (score 22):

I solved the issue by moving the following folder to a backup:

`~/.config/google-chrome/PepperFlash` moved to `~/.config/google-chrome/PepperFlash.bak`

After that kill all processes of Chrome (also the background ones for offline gmail and so on).

It works now for me. Must have to do something with the new rule that you have to enable plugins per page/site before they run maybe?

Comment: I read about that but I thought it was only Firefox.

Comment: This is the correct answer, and gets your PEP plugin working again.

Comment: Here is official issue discussion on google's tracker https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=173790

Comment: Worked for me too.

Comment: It worked! On Ubuntu 12.10 and Chrome Version Version 24.0.1312.57. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

1. Open up Google Chrome
2. Type *chrome://plugins* into the address bar
3. Look for **Adobe Flash Player**
4. Click on **+Details** in the upper right corner
5. **Disable** one of the **Adobe Flash Player** entries, and make sure one is **Enabled**

If you have installed the package `flashplugin-installer` you'll see two plug-ins, you can choose whichever you want.

For some reason it was *disabled* and at the beggining of the list you can also see another `libpepflashplayer` which is also disabled.

Comment: I have this same issue and I have typed in the the about://plugins and everything is enabled and still get the error couldn't load plugin

Comment: @rstreeter78 Is every flash plugin you have enabled?

Comment: Yes I believe so here are links to the images http://imagebin.org/245133  http://imagebin.org/245134

Comment: @rstreeter78 Try with one plug in at a time they might be conflicting with each other.

Comment: I tried that and was unsuccessful

Comment: Clean everything from Chrome, use it's built in cleaning options, close the browser, and try again.

Comment: Make sure you click the somewhat inconspicuous "+Details" button in the top right corner of chrome://plugins -- this will separate the flash entry in two, allowing you to disable one of them.

Comment: I did this (disabled Chrome's libpep... and enabled Adobe's .SO) and it worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

In `chrome://plugins`, I disabled `libpepflashplayer`. Now I can watch youtube and Dateline. :D

Comment: oh..Just an update. OK to watch Dateline.. but can't watch on ABC.com. It's just blank... no error message.

Answer (score 5):

I can't seem to add a comment to Uri Herrara's answer, or even up vote it. But he set me on the right track.

Ubuntu installed a new image and Chrome, and the `libpepflashplayer.so` Flash player is not working. I disabled it, and the

```
Name:   Shockwave Flash  
Version:    11.2 r202  
Location:   /opt/google/chrome/plugins/libflashplayer.so
```

is working fine

Comment: If you want to learn more about how this site works, I suggest reading the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq) and [About](http://askubuntu.com/about) pages.  Good luck and have fun!

Answer (score 3):

Don't know why, but the pepperflash plugin used by chrome seems to be crashing recently.  Removing the plugin completely will do the trick temporarily, but will be recreated automatically at some point in time, probably after a relaunch of the browser or something.

```
rm -fr ~/.config/google-chrome/PepperFlash
```

This is the command to remove the plugin.  Launching chrome thereafter should allow you to play flash via it defaulting back to the default adobe plugin.

If you don't want to go around blowing away directories, you can rename it:

```
mv ~/.config/google-chrome/PepperFlash ~/.config/google-chrome/PepperFlash.bak
```

It works too.

Again, just a temporary work around, but it works in a pinch until they fix PepperFlash.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get flash playing again by just disabling `libpepflashplayer` in Chrome via `chrome://plugins/`, no terminal needed, didn't even restart Chrome. Strangely I did not have any issues with Firefox.

Comment: I was also thinking why would Firefox have an issue when the pepper flash is for Chrome only. Oddly enough it was the only step I did.

Answer (score 1):

Well got lucky. Did the following after closing both browsers. Go to a terminal and:

`rm -r  ~/.config/google-chrome/PepperFlash`

Then open any of the 2 browsers and go to their respective plugins section.

For Firefox it is in the menu in **Tools --> Addons --> Plugins** and check to be sure that the Shockwave Plugin is **Enabled**. Then test any flash video.

For Chrome, type in the URL: `chrome://plugins` and check that the plugin is checked there as **Always Enabled**.

Right now am testing to make sure both are working fine.

UPDATE - Yeap, both are working correctly again. Maybe it was an update that left a confusion there with the PepperFlash file.

Answer (score 1):

The new release, Version 24.0.1312.69 has fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple go to `chrome://plugins` and disable `/opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so`.

Everything works like charm.