# Google chrome - flash plugin crashes

Tags: 12.04, flash, google-chrome, plugins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Youtube - couldn’t load plug-in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250448/youtube-couldnt-load-plug-in)

Everything works fine, but yesterday, after update I cant load any flash video in google chrome. I can see "Couldn't load plug-in".

However flash works in firefox.

ubuntu 12.04 - 64b
google chrome 24.0.1312.57

Could anyone help me?